# Countably Additive Set Function Dealing with Extended Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Define $n(E):=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \infty,& \text{if E is a not finite set} \\ 
 |E|,& \text{if E is a finite set.} 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Let  $\lbrace E_i\rbrace$ be an arbitrary sequence of disjoint sets of real numbers. I am wanting to show $n(\cup E_i)=\sum n(E_i)$ by using [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). [Note this [problem](http://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/books/royden-fitzpatrick/royden-fitzpatrick.pdf) is essentially the same as page 31, i.e. #4 (p. 42 of the pdf).]

I am going to as best I can fill in all the gaps for the lower limit sum relative to the index of the set.

> Let $\lbrace E_i \rbrace_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an arbitrary sequence of  disjoint (pairwise) sets of real numbers.
>
> I am again wanting to show $n(\bigcup\lbrace E_i \rbrace_{i \in \mathbb{N}})=\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}n(E_i)$.

However, this does not make sense to me as I could easily make up a function $E: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where the correspondence is given by $E_j=\lbrace j \rbrace$, so then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}n(E_i)&=|E_1|+|E_2|+|E_3|+...\\
&=|\lbrace 1 \rbrace |+|\lbrace 2 \rbrace|+|\lbrace 3 \rbrace|+...\\
&=1+1+1+...\\
\end{align*}
which I thought would not be defined in this context. So what am I doing wrong here? Is the lower index of summation not supposed to be natural numbers $\mathbb{N}:=\lbrace 1, 2, 3, ... \rbrace$ or is the sequence part what I am messing up on? $\textbf{Question:}$ What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is no contradiction. The sum is infinite, just like $n(\bigcup E_i) =n(\mathbb N)=\infty$.

Comment: Why do you think it is "clearly not right"?

Comment: Why does the sum $1+1+1+...=\infty$. Isn't the expansion of all the summands not an extended real number? Are you saying $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N} }n(E_i)=|E_1|+|E_2|+|E_3|+...=\infty$?

Comment: That's what I thought was a contradiction here, but maybe I am mistaken as I thought that $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N} }n(E_i)=|E_1|+|E_2|+|E_3|+...$ is not defined.

Comment: So "clearly not right here" means I thought the "sum is not well-defined" which I guess might be well-defined due to my lack of understanding.

Comment: I changed the wording of the question to hopefully help out with the wording. I am particularly confused as to why $1+1+1+...=\infty$. I understand that $\infty=n(\bigcup\lbrace E_i \rbrace_{i \in \mathbb{N}})$, but I do not understand why $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N} }n(E_i)=\infty$ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you are confused as to why $$1+1+\dots=\infty.$$
An infinite sum is defined as the limit of the partial sums, and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n1=\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\infty.$$

> I though the sum was not well defined.

The sum is not well-defined if you only consider real numbers to be well defined. But this is the point of creating the extended real numbers in the first place. We want to be able to talk about $\infty$, so we formally add it to our number system.

What would be the point of having an $\infty$ symbol if you still had to say $1+1+\dots$ was undefined?

---

In the extended reals, we add the symbols $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, and we extend some of the structure of the reals (addition, multiplication, order, suprema, infinima and limits)  to these symbols.

Specifically, just like a sequence of reals can have a real limit, a sequence of extended reals can have an extended real limit. The phrase "$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=L$", where $a_n$ and $L$ are extended reals, means the same thing when $L$ is a normal real number. When $L=+\infty$, we *define* that phrase to mean
$$
\text{ for all } N>0 \text{ there exists } M \in \mathbb N:n\ge M\implies a_n \ge N.
$$
Using this definition, it is easy to prove $1+1+\dots=\infty$ by proving the limit of the partial sums is infinity.

If you cannot accept this explanation, you need to find an authority who can define what limits mean for the extended real numbers.

Comment: This was helpful, but I do not understand why $1+1+...=\infty$ here. Conceptually, it makes sense but by the book I do not understand it completely. What is the definition of infinity you are using here? I would guess that $1+1+1+...=\infty$ here by some concept of measure, but I am not sure. Any help in that way would be much appreciated!

Comment: Infinity is not "defined" per se. It is added to the reals as a formal symbol. We define how it behaves with respect to addition $(+\infty+a=+\infty$ unless $a=-\infty$, etc), how it behaves with respect to multiplcation $(a\cdot \pm\infty=\pm\infty$, when $a>0$, etc), and defined what it means to have $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=L$ or $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty$. You then realize these are pretty consistent with the usual concepts of addition and limits for the reals, and that the limit definition implies $\sum_i 1=\infty$. These rules work nicely with measure theory.   @W.G.

Comment: @W.G. Topologically, $\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty. + \infty\}$ has the order topology wrt the usual order of the reals extended by $-\infty < x < +\infty$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In this order topology a basic neighbourhood looks like $O_M:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x > M\} \cup \{+\infty\}$, and it's clear that the limit of the sequence $x_n = n$ (the partial sums of $1 + 1 + \ldots$) is $+\infty$ by the Archimedean property of the reals.

Comment: How is $O_M$ to define infinity with the order topology here. I have not dealt with order topologies, but I am wanting to know how to deal with a limit of a sequence with partial sums like you describe. Is $O_M$ somehow affiliated with the definition $\forall U, (x\in U\rightarrow [\exists N\in \mathbb{N}: \forall n\in \mathbb{N}^{\geq N}, x_n\in U])$ where $U$ is an open set.

Comment: @W.G. See edit. Henro's explanation is good if you are familiar with concepts, but is not necessary. The rules of the extended reals are simply defined arbitrarily, so you need to understand and accept those definitions. However, the definitions are chosen so things match our intuition and work out nicely.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted! Thank you! I am sorry I didn't notice you edited your answer until now.